# Error when build XBMC binary for Rasbperry

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, xbmc

I follow [this](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianXBMC) instructions for build and install XBMC binary in raspberry PI (Occidentails), but when delete sse2 instructions from makefile i see this error when try to *make*:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/xbmc-rbp/lib/libdvd'
In file included from simd.h:34:0,
                 from clusterfit.h:32,
                 from clusterfit.cpp:27:
simd_sse.h:29:23: fatal error: xmmintrin.h: No such file or directory
```

I searched in google an Stackoverflow w/o any solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SSE is still included.
 Did you fix up the sse part in the makefile ?

```
sed -i 's/-msse2//' lib/libsquish/Makefile
sed -i 's/-DSQUISH_USE_SSE=2//' lib/libsquish/Makefile
```

you can see from the ./configure output if SSE is enabled.